# How to enable/disable Finish button in the Docusign Embedded User Signature Experience?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is there a way to enable/disable **Finish** button in the Docusign Embedded User Signature Experience only after the user has provided a Signature, currently the **Finish** Button gets enabled if any of the Fields are drag-dropped into the document.So is there any setting to enable or disable the Finish button only based on the **Signature** field and not the other fields like **"Initial","Date Signed"** etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Free-form signing allows the recipient to place any field in any location, and complete the signing experience after placing any field.

If you want to require a signature, you'll need to place the relevant tags prior to sending.